# Position a variable-width div by it's midpoint

Tags: css

Given a horizontal offset (z), I want to horizontally move variable-width div by it's midpoint to that offset, rather than it's leftmost or rightmost edge.

Since it's variable-width, I cannot simply use half of a fixed-width value to calculate an offset to get the midpoint of the div to (z)

also, the div is absolutely positioned, so it does not take the full width by default

an incorrect example is here:

http://jsbin.com/rejaduxepe/edit?html,css,output

```css
.bar {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: solid 1px #F09;
}

.value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  background-color: #0F9;
  border: solid 1px #F90;
  color: #000;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="value">123v452</div>
</div>
```

I do not simply want to center the div `value` in the center of `bar`.

I want the "midpoint" of the `value` div to be `20%` from the start of `bar`, but I don't know how wide the `value` div is.

The code above puts the "leftmost" portion of `value` to be `20%` from the start of `bar`, instead of the "midpoint" of `value` to be `20%` from the start of `bar`

Comment: In case you wonder about the downvotes, one of them is from me. A div by default is full width. If its variable, you must have done something to it already, like displaying it as inline-block, or setting a width. Depending on that situation, there are various solutions like, text-align, margins, absolute positioning or transforms. I'm a bit disappointed that a user with as many questions and answers as yourself would post a question with this little context, making it hard or even impossible to point out the solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `transform: translateX(-50%)` which will move it *left* by half of its *width*:

```css
.bar {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: solid 1px #F09;
}

.value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #0F9;
  border: solid 1px #F90;
  color: #000;
  left: 20%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="value">123v452</div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use absolute positioning and translate the elements with or you can use flex on the parent element.

```
div{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

or

```
.divWrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```